# Editing a Datasource Sql Select statement to take text box inputs

Tags: sql, select, gridview, datasource

I am trying to create a grid view that is editable and allows deleting, with a WHERE clause that takes its input from a text box on the click of a button.

I Know how to get the select statement taking the text box result into account and can produce the string, but is there a way i can then update the data source select statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, let the Data Configuration tool do the work.  You want to get to this screen:

[image]

The rendered Update statement and parameters look something like this:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TestTable] SET [CustomerName] = @CustomerName, [Status] = @Status, [phone] = @phone, [CustomerDate] = @CustomerDate WHERE [ID] = @ID">

<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerName" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="Int16" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="phone" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerDate" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```